# Merge df: no error, but output only header line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, large-data

I am trying to merge a small dataframe (dfSmall) that can fit into memory with a huge dataframe (dfLarge) that can't fit in memory. They're both too big to post here but look something like:

```
dfSmall:
ix,#CHROM,POS,sample,allele,pop,super_pop
0,1,1121557,rs112904239,HG00096,T,GBR,EUR
1,1,1213223,rs113095492,HG00096,T,GBR,EUR
2,1,1000894,rs114006445,HG00096,T,GBR,EUR
(5000 rows)

dfLarge:
#CHROM POS      ID          REF ALT QUAL FILTER
1      14719    rs527865771 C   A   100 PASS   ...
1      14728    rs547701710 C   A   100 PASS   ...
1      1213223  rs113095492 A   G   100 PASS   ...
...
(>1 million rows, >2000 columns)

#for just these three rows, my output would the row where 1, 1213223 match:
dfMerge:
#CHROM POS      ID          REF ALT QUAL FILTER
  1    1213223  rs113095492 A   G   100  PASS
```

Here's my code:

```
dfSmall = pd.read_table('small.csv', dtype='str', header=None, skiprows=1, names=['ix', '#CHROM', 'POS', 'ID', 'sample', 'allele', 'pop', 'superpop'])

def merge_it(c):
        return dfSmall.merge(c, on=['#CHROM', 'POS'], suffixes=('', '_y'))[header_line]

dfFull = pd.concat([merge_it(c) for c in pd.read_table(large.vcf.gz, header = None, names = header_line, dtype='str', engine = 'c',compression = 'gzip', skiprows=251, chunksize=40000, low_memory=False)])

match = re.search(r'ALL.(chr\d+)', chromosome)
dfFull.to_csv(r"{}.csv".format(match.group(1)))
```

where `header_line` = `['#CHROM','POS','ID','REF','ALT','QUAL','FILTER',..., 2500 strings]`

When I run it, I get no errors, but my output file is only the header:

```
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  HG00096 HG00097 HG00099 HG00100 HG00101 HG00102     ...
```

I have manually checked a few of the entries, so I know there are rows from both files that visually match in both the `#CHROM` and `POS` columns.

I thought the problem of getting an output file with only the header might be because the column data types didn't match, which is why I explicitly set `dtype='str'`. However, checking the dtypes for dfLarge gives me `dtype('O')`, not `str`. Could they be mismatching on the `#CHROM/POS` columns because the dtypes are different? If that's not an issue, any other ideas?

Comment: Could you add the exact merged form of the data for the example above.

Comment: You mean the output file? Sure, added! The whole thing is over 2000 columns, so I pasted in the first dozen to give an idea.

Comment: I meant the merged form of the two excerpts from dfSmall and dfLarge. One can try to figure out what you want to achieve from your code but looking at it is not clear whether you coded your intentions correctly.

Comment: Oh okay, I updated everything to look more like my real data and then gave an example of what the output should be for that subset.

Comment: This looks better. Can you add the column and index names?

Comment: Sure, added to the example sets - I set the column names when I import the files.

Comment: Have you tried with datasets small enough to play around with? And then slowly add back stuff until it breaks.

Comment: I can't create a dataset so small for my dataframes that it works. That is, if I cull both datasets to only 50 lines (with a few that ensure I would get an output), it still only gives the header as output using this code. This is why I thought it might be a `dtype` problem.

Comment: Have you checked that the `dtypes` match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the way you parse your file - dfSmall has commas in it. Here is what I get once I have removed the commas:

```
df_m = pd.merge(dfSmall, dfLarge, on=['POS', 'CHROM'], how='inner')


dfSmall
Out[100]: 
   CHROM      POS       sample   allele pop super pop.1
0      1  1121557  rs112904239  HG00096   T   GBR   EUR
1      1  1213223  rs113095492  HG00096   T   GBR   EUR
2      1  1000894  rs114006445  HG00096   T   GBR   EUR

dfLarge
Out[102]: 
   CHROM      POS           ID REF ALT  QUAL FILTER
0      1    14719  rs527865771   C   A   100   PASS
1      1    14728  rs547701710   C   A   100   PASS
2      1  1213223  rs113095492   A   G   100   PASS

df_m
Out[103]: 
   CHROM      POS       sample   allele pop super pop.1           ID REF ALT  \
0      1  1213223  rs113095492  HG00096   T   GBR   EUR  rs113095492   A   G   

   QUAL FILTER  
0   100   PASS
```

Comment: Wow, yep, I'm so used to `read_csv` that I didn't have the `sep=','` in there!

Comment: Excellent! I am glad it is sorted.